# Using SQL Server with PHP

Tags: php, sql-server-2008-r2

PHP was originally made to interface with MYSQL. I'm wondering what is the difficulty level and how the best way to go about using PHP with SQL Server 2008 r2 is. I've done some research and it seems like there are some usable libraries. Is this something that is feasible on the production level?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PHP has a library for dealing with MSSQL (http://php.net/manual/en/book.mssql.php).  You also might consider using something like PDO with its appropriate driver (http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-sqlsrv.php) if you would like a more abstracted library to work with.

Answer (score 0):

There is a SQL Server driver that works under windows: http://www.microsoft.com/en-ca/download/details.aspx?id=20098

http://php.net/manual/en/book.mssql.php

Answer (score 0):

take a look at http://puurunen.ca/blog/?p=139 
You should find there some info on sql server 2008 r2  PDO implementation